# wpf wait for vsync (Image)

Tags: wpf, vsync, tearing

I use a UDP API that updates a camera feed to a ImageSource, I have a timer that updates the ViewModel's ImageSource and then WPF databinds the Image on screen.

The timer has an interval that fires as many times as the refresh rate, but offourse this does not mean its in sync with the screen update so I get tearing.

With SlimDX, XNA opengl etc its easy to sync to the refresh rate, how should I solve it with WPF?

Comment: Any luck? Got bad tearing for WriteableBitmap (pure software updates) as well as SharpDX (D3D Interop)

Comment: Sadly no, I didnt find any solution for this :/

Comment: boo. WPF how rubbish can you get. Oh well - if you ever do, please email me (or comment here)!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that this is not possible at the moment.

Have a look at [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6cab7bb4-c159-4234-9c0f-c977b74eac54) and [this one too](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/693fbedb-efa6-413e-ab66-530c6961d3fb)

Comment: Thats really bad, I thought WPF was supposed to be flexible for media intense apps. Can i somehow render SLIMDX content in a wpf window?

Comment: Yes you can! In the samples of SlimDX there is an example of WPF integration.

Comment: Will check that out, I need to be ablet o have overlayed WPF (HUD) controls over the SLIMFX content.. I hope that is possible, will have to check it out..